# One Minute After Midnight - C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Scenario:  I am passing a date to SQL server from a C# application and want the value to be the first minute of Jan 02, 2018. Which would be the correct way to parse this?

```
DateTime sDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-01-02 0:01:00", "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss", null);
```

OR

```
DateTime sDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-01-02 12:01:00:AM", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:tt", null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dates are fixed so there is no need to parse from a string, use the [appropriate constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
sDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Also if you need UTC date do not forgot to specify DateTimeKind: `new DateTime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);`